# Is there any way to configure or personalize the official android error reporting process?

Tags: android, reporting, configure

For example the message of [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/S_dvbdbhxfI/AAAAAAAAAFs/ljOkUg62o6g/s1600/gfb2.png) activity? Or the design of it?

I would be happy to hear about some possibilities.

I know, there are great 3rd party solutions, but before i choose one of them, i would like to give a chance to the official solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to configure or personalize the official android error reporting process?

No, unless you are creating your own firmware.

> For example the message of this activity? Or the design of it?

No and no, unless you are creating your own firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Look for interface `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and static method  `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`. In two words: create your own class, implementing this interface, and register it in `onCreate` of `Activity` or `Application`.